# Multiple versions of Newtonsoft.json when compiling

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, json.net, nuget

Im working on a mixed ASP.NET, class library project in .NET using Framework 4.6.1.
When compiling a prjoect I get the following error:

```
Error   CS0433  The type 'JObject' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' and 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'    KBTryk3 D:\SourceCodes\Trykonline_3\Source\KBTryk3\Controllers\Api\CustomerController.cs
```

The v6.0.0.0 used to exist in the solution but I updated to 12.x.x.x via the nuget package manager and now It wont compile due to this error.
I've searched across the whole solution but I can't find any reference to the old newtonsoft library.

Any suggestions as to where to start?

Comment: Are you using .net core or .net framework? Also, have you tried to 'Clean Solution' and 'Rebuild Solution'?

Comment: did you take a look inside your project file?

Comment: I've done a thorough search through all the files in my solution folder.
I've tried clean/rebuild too..
The only place I can find a reference to v6.0.0.0 is in a file called csprojAssemblyReference.cache
It can be deleted but it rebuilds itself with the same info when compiling.

Comment: Is this a .NET app or .NET Core app?

Comment: it sounds to me like another nuget package you're using might bundle newtonsoft.json.dll inside their own package, so when you compile, two different versions of the dll are passed to the compiler. I suggest using `msbuild -bl` to build, then open `msbuild.binlog` with http://msbuildlog.com and search for newtonsoft.json to find where the two versions are coming from.

Comment: Thanks Zivkan. Using your suggestion I found out it was ABCPdf.

Comment: What you need is an assembly redirect. That's why I was asking about the type of app but you never answered so...

Comment: Sorry JuanR..  I've been AFK for some hours..  I'm targeting .net framework 4.6.1 as I wrote in the question..

Comment: No worries. Are you seeing this error in a library project or web application project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have two projects referencing different versions of Newtonsoft. It's also possible you are using a library that requires a particular version of Newtonsoft, other than the one referenced by your project.

Inspect the references of every project in the solution and make sure that, if Newtonsoft is present, it points to the right version (v12.0.0.0).

If that doesn't fix it, then add an assembly redirect to the config file of the project that is causing the error:

```
<configuration> 
    <!-- other sections in your file here -->
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This will cause any references to older versions to be routed to the new one.

Comment: Yea. I came to this conclusion too.  In the web.config I suppose, but it doesn't seem to do anything.
I've read that the xml-namespace is important, so I've put that in the auto-generated binding, but no cigar..
Downgrading to Newtonsoft v6.x.x.x helps offcourse but...  ..thats not really a fix in my oppinion, just a workaround.

Comment: @HenrikClausen: You mentioned you found out it was `ABCPdf`. You could try adding an app.config file to the library that references this component. That should fix it.

Comment: Yea I did try that too

Comment: @HenrikClausen: That's exactly what assembly redirects are meant to fix so I would suggest you take another look. You must have missed one somewhere.